# How to assign values randomly between dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to randomly assign values from one column in one dataframe, to another dataframe within 12 different categories (by agerange and gender). For example I have two dataframes; lets call one d1 and the other d2

```
  d1:
index agerange gender income
 0     2        1      56700
 1     2        0      25600
 2     4        0      3000
 3     4        0      106000
 4     3        0      200
 5     3        0      43000
 6     4        0      10000000

d2:
index agerange gender 
 0     3        0      
 1     2        0      
 2     4        0      
 3     4        0
```

I want to group both dataframes by agerange and gender i.e 0-1,2,3,4,5,6 & 1-1,2,3,4,5,6 then randomly chose one of the incomes within d1 and assign it to d2.

ie:

```
d1:
index agerange gender income
 0     2        1      56700
 1     2        0      25600
 2     4        0      3000
 3     4        0      106000
 4     3        0      200
 5     3        0      43000
 6     4        0      10000000

d2:
index agerange gender  income
 0     3        0      200  
 1     2        0      25600 
 2     4        0      10000000
 3     4        0      3000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
An approach with `np.random.choice` and `pd.DataFrame.query`
I'm making an implicit assumption that we replace randomly drawn values for every row.

```
def take_one(x):
    q = 'agerange == {agerange} and gender == {gender}'.format(**x)
    return np.random.choice(d1.query(q).income)

d2.assign(income=d2.apply(take_one, 1))

       agerange  gender  income
index                          
0             3       0     200
1             2       0   25600
2             4       0  106000
3             4       0  106000
```

---

**Option 2**
Attempting to make it more efficient to call `np.random.choice` once per group.

```
g = d1.groupby(['agerange', 'gender']).income.apply(list)
f = lambda x: pd.Series(np.random.choice(g.get(x.name, [0] * len(x)), len(x)), x.index)
d2.groupby(['agerange', 'gender'], group_keys=False).apply(f)

       agerange  gender    income
index                            
0             3       0       200
1             2       0     25600
2             4       0  10000000
3             4       0    106000
```

---

**Debugging and Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'agerange': [2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4],
        'gender': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        'income': [56700, 25600, 3000, 106000, 200, 43000, 10000000]
    }, pd.Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], name='index')
)

d2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'agerange': [3, 2, 4, 4], 'gender': [0, 0, 0, 0]},
    pd.Index([0, 1, 2, 3], name='index')
)

g = d1.groupby(['agerange', 'gender']).income.apply(list)
f = lambda x: pd.Series(np.random.choice(g.loc[x.name], len(x)), x.index)
d2.assign(income=d2.groupby(['agerange', 'gender'], group_keys=False).apply(f))
```

---

```
       agerange  gender  income
index                          
0             3       0     200
1             2       0   25600
2             4       0  106000
3             4       0    3000
```

Comment: Hello, I attempted your option 2 suggestion and got the error **IndexingError: Too many indexers** do you have any idea what could be causing this problem?

Comment: @kstav I added a section where you can copy and paste the code exactly.  If it produces the desire result then the issue is with your specific dataframe.  If there is still an issue, then the problem must be with versions or something.

Comment: the specific code you posted does work, I will see what the root issue could be. Thanks

Comment: I think I figured out the issue, if there is a category in the second data frame that does not exist in the first one it gives the error **IndexingError: Too many indexers** not sure exactly how to proceed

Comment: I updated **Option 2** with a hack that returns zero when the pair is missing.

Answer (score 3):

How about creating a dictionary of incomes based on ageranges and then map the random choice  i.e

```
#Based on unutbu's data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'agerange': [2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4], 'gender': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'income': [56700, 25600, 3000, 106000, 200, 43000, 10000000], 'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'agerange': [3, 2, 4, 4], 'gender': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'index': [0, 1, 2, 3]})

age_groups = df1.groupby('agerange')['income'].agg(lambda x: tuple(x)).to_dict()
df2['income'] = df2['agerange'].map(lambda x: np.random.choice(age_groups[x]))
```

Output :

```
  agerange  gender  index  income
0         3       0      0   43000
1         2       0      1   25600
2         4       0      2  106000
3         4       0      3  106000
```

If gender group is also required then you can use apply if you want to fill 0 for keys not found you can use if else  i.e

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'agerange': [3, 2, 6, 4], 'gender': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'index': [0, 1, 2, 3]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'agerange': [2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4], 'gender': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'income': [56700, 25600, 3000, 106000, 200, 43000, 10000000], 'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})


age_groups = df1.groupby(['agerange','gender'])['income'].agg(lambda x: tuple(x)).to_dict()
df2['income'] = df2.apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(age_groups[x['agerange'],x['gender']]) if (x['agerange'],x['gender']) in age_groups else 0,axis=1)
```

Output :

```
   agerange  gender  index  income
0         3       0      0   43000
1         2       0      1   25600
2         6       0      2       0
3         4       0      3  106000
```

Answer (score 3):

```
d2['income'] = d2.apply(lambda x: d1.loc[(d1.agerange==x.agerange) &(d1.gender == x.gender),'income'].sample(n=1).max(),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   index  agerange  gender  income
0      0         3       0     200
1      1         2       0   25600
2      2         4       0    3000
3      3         4       0  106000
```